# How to achieve a Multi-Page website while using MEAN Stack or similar?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application, mean-stack

I have spent the past few months learning Angular and the MEAN stack, and I am starting my first major application for production. However, because of the intended eventual scale of the website, it makes sense for the website to NOT be a single page app. I would like the website to be fast and responsive like other Angular apps, but I would prefer at least the major pages to be able to reload in the browser, if anything for SEO.

My question is, can I achieve multi-paged websites using Angular? If not, what should I use? Can I still use Express? I want to avoid using ruby on rails.

Comment: Of course you can, MEAN stack apps is not equal to SPA (single page apps).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can use express to render static HTML. I imagine you are doing this for your landing and information pages.

Example

`var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

In your public directory, you have a `index.html` file with your landing page.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. This is correct, not to mention .sendFile and .render(). MEAN has several ways to serve up multiple pages.

Comment: Thanks! If this is the case, why do many insist Angular is solely for SPA's?

Comment: @TristanC the common way to use Angular is in a SPA, you will lose much the benefit of don't reloading everything when changing pages. But yeah, you can use it the way you want.